# "Internal connection fatal error" from TdsParser when calling native compiled stored procedure in SQL Server 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I am having huge problems with the current SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2070.41) and native compiled stored procedures when calling them from the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (1.1.0 and lower).

It *is* working when either using SQL Server 2017 or `System.Data.SqlClient`.
[I am also having the same problem in Java with the JDBC driver.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559872/tdsparser-encountered-unexpected-unknown-token-0xa3)

Apparently the `TdsParser` is receiving data it doesn't expect from the SQL Server connection and is throwing an exception during the parsing.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

Example code which should reproduce the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True";    
            const string prod = @"CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.NativeProdForTesting WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
                AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH ( TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT,  LANGUAGE = N'us_english')
                    SELECT NULL AS testcol
                RETURN 0
                END";

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using var createSp = con.CreateCommand();
                createSp.CommandText = prod;
                con.Open();
                createSp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            try
            {
                using var con = new SqlConnection(connString);
                using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[NativeProdForTesting]";
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("NO ERROR!");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why not just [create an issue then](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues)? Any difference between `System.Data.SqlClient` and `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` where the latter produces an internal error and the former does not, with all other things being equal, is obviously a bug (because, at the very least, even if this scenario is somehow deliberately not supported, it should give a descriptive error).

Comment: Yup, seems like you found a bug.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/365)